# i have been facing some trouble with the javascript qutation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to alert the variable magic to see whether the code is ok or not, but the console only shows an error in the var magic line. Can someone explain to me why it shows this error? Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
      var string="Let's play with colour";
      var color=Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
      var magic='<span style="color:'#'+color+">'+string+'</span>';
      alert(magic);
</script>
```

Comment: because you have nested quotes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the wrong placed string terminators, you need to pad the string with leading zeros for getting always a lenght of six characters.

```js
var string = "Let's play with colour";
var color = ('00000' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)).slice(-6);
var magic = '<span style="color: #' + color + '">' + string + '</span>';
console.log(magic);
```

Answer (score 1):

That line should be this:

```
var magic='<span style="color:#'+color+'">'+string+'</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of errors with quotation marks on that line.

Try this:

```
<script>
      var string = "Let's play with colour";
      var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
      var magic = '<span style="color: #'+color+'">'+string+'</span>';
      alert(magic);
</script>
```